# Compare the values of columns in rows(large datasets) and update only if they are different

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have two different tables and I am extracting the data from table1 and dumping the data into table2. Before dumping, I am just deleting the existing data in the table2 and dumping the data fetched from table1. Both this tables have around 500k record sets. And this happens every day.

Now I am retrieving the data in table2 using JDBC application and doing some processing.

Instead of deleting the whole existing data now I wanted to extract the data from table1 and compare with existing data in table2 and update only the modified data instead of whole data. Also I need to process only modified data from table2. What is the best and optimized way to do this. I can add or modify the table schema for table2 to indicate that this rows are modified as well.

Also do I have to do the comparison in Java application or SQL which would be the best option and how to do that?

Comment: would it be a good idea to use a after insert or update trigger on table 1 to update or insert corresponding values in table 2 in the sql db?

Comment: Do you have some sample script ?@YHStan

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the required SQL-server syntax to provide a script, however I found a tutorial website which would be helpful to update values in table 2 based on updates in table 1. Please do take a look https://www.tutorialgateway.org/after-update-triggers-in-sql-server/

Comment: Sounds like you should use [`MERGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)